# PARTITION BY with TUMBLE causes exception in FlinkSQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I would like to select last element of processing window using FlinkSQL. Tried to achieve that with `ROW_NUMBER` in Blink planner. Tried following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT key, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS rn
    FROM InputTable
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY key, TUMBLE(rt, INTERVAL '15' MINUTE) ORDER BY -ts)
) WHERE rn = 1

// rt = ts.rowtime, ts is Long
```

Unfortunately, this causes exception

```
org.apache.flink.table.planner.codegen.CodeGenException: Unsupported call: TUMBLE(TIMESTAMP(3) *ROWTIME*, INTERVAL SECOND(3) NOT NULL) 
If you think this function should be supported, you can create an issue and start a discussion for it.
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I was thinking about `TUMBLE` function as something "equivalent"  to calculating `rowtime % interval`.

Answer (score 0):

`TUMBLE` (as well as `HOP` and `SESSION`) are special built-in functions in Flink SQL (version 2.11) that can only be used in a `GROUP BY` clause. In principle you are right and it should be OK to use `TUMBLE` in this context, but it is simply not supported at this point.

You could implement a user-defined function to re-implement the grouping logic of `TUMBLE` however, I would not recommend that because the query would not perform well. Flink SQL would not be aware that a partition (`PARTITION BY key, TUMBLE(rt, INTERVAL '15' MINUTE`) would only be "active" for 35 minutes and keep its state forever. Hence, the query would accumulate more and more state over time which slows down checkpointing and recovery. IMO, such time-based `OVER` partitions should be supported in the future, but AFAIK they are not yet.